# Github push a local fork of a repository?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I'm in the following situation: there is a repository "XYZ" on Github which I have a local copy of in a folder "XYZ_local" on my computer (which contains the `.git` folder and everything). The files in "XYZ_local" are several versions behind the "XYZ" repository that's on Github today.

I've made changes in "XYZ_local" and now I just want to upload it to my own remote Github account such that it appears as a "fork" of the actual "XYZ" repository.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to continue to receive changes from the remote repository in the future?

Comment: No, I just want to put my work on github while making sure that it is cited as a fork of the original "XYZ" repo rather than my own work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to actually fork the project on github. Like go to the project page and click the fork button.

Then commit your changes and make sure you pull from the current remote. That will integrate your changes with the new commits in the remote. After that, remove the remote pointing at XYZ.
`git remote remove origin`

Then add the new remote to point to your new fork.
`git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/XYZ.git`

If you want to keep receiving changes from the remote repository follow these instructions :
https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/